# Conversion from empty Date to type 'Date' is not valid

Tags: vb.net

My Function works fine until I return an empty or NULL result, then i get the error: `Conversion from string "" to type 'Date' is not valid.`

VB.NET:

```
Public Function GetNextWaitListed(ByVal ClassName As String, ByVal ClassDate As Date, ByVal ClassTime As String) As String
    Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("TechTrainingConn")
    Dim conn As New Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connStr)
    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT Min(SubmitTime) FROM [EnrollmentsTbl]" & _
                       " WHERE [ClassName] = """ & ClassName & """" & _
                       " AND [ClassDate] = #" & ClassDate & "#" & _
                       " AND [ClassTime] = """ & ClassTime & """" & _
                       " AND [Waitlisted] = True" & _
                       " AND [Completed] = False" & _
                       " AND [Enrolled] = True" 
        Dim comm As New Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
        Dim result As Date = comm.ExecuteScalar()

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(result) Then
            Return result
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try

End Function
```

I have tried the following but am a little confused since I returning a `date`

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(result) Then
   Dim oDate As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(result)
   Return oDate
End If
```

Comment: Never ever glue bits of string and data together to create a query.  Always use SQL parameters

Comment: access database I can't modify

Comment: No one said anything about the DB, but that SQL in the code

Comment: ok, how would I resolve this issue?

Comment: ***Always use SQL parameters***

Comment: ok, are you going to help or not?

Comment: There are several major issues in that code a) very very bad SQL, b) No Option Strict c) using a global connection d) leaking resources.  These are all easily researched and even covered here in post after post after post.

Comment: I'm not saying your wrong, its just as a infrequent programmer trying to fix a project, I'm looking for help. yes my code is messy at best but I'm trying to resolve an issue - any help by example would be appreciated.

Comment: If you use [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) then Visual Studio will show you were there are variable type mismatches. E.g. the code shows `Function GetNextWaitListed(...) As String` but you wrote you wanted to return a DateTime. Also, what do you want to return if the SQL query returned no rows, and you need `conn.Dispose()` after `conn.Close()`.

Comment: here's a hint for the one problem you know: `ExecuteScalar` never ever returns a Date/DateTime.  It always returns Object.  Get the object and test *that*.  Dont use `Convert` but DateTime.TryParse.  Additionally, the error message indicates that dates/times are stored as string?  That would add `e)` to the list

Comment: The message actually tells you what the problems is. Your string is empty. You can't put an empty string and expect the computer to figure out what you want him to do with an empty string.

Comment: Ignoring the other problems, after you declare `result` as `Object` What do you want the program to do when it does encounter an empty string? return a default date? You could return a date that is outside your range of dates, for example #01/01/1900# or do you want to return a null value to the calling code and have the calling code deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution for me was to return into object and if object was empty do the else with dummy date

```
Public Function GetNextWaitListed(ByVal ClassName As String, ByVal ClassDate As Date, ByVal ClassTime As String) As String
    Dim connStr As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("TechTrainingConn")
    Dim conn As New Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(connStr)

    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim sql As String = "SELECT Min(SubmitTime) FROM [EnrollmentsTbl]" & _
                       " WHERE [ClassName] = """ & ClassName & """" & _
                       " AND [ClassDate] = #" & ClassDate & "#" & _
                       " AND [ClassTime] = """ & ClassTime & """" & _
                       " AND [Waitlisted] = True" & _
                       " AND [Completed] = False" & _
                       " AND [Enrolled] = True" 
        Dim comm As New Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
        Dim Obj As Object = comm.ExecuteScalar()
            If (Obj IsNot Nothing) AndAlso (Obj IsNot DBNull.Value) Then
                Dim matches As String = Obj.ToString
                Dim result As Date = Convert.ToDateTime(matches)
                Return result
            Else
                Dim result As Date = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/1900")
                Return result
            End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Response.Write(ex)
        If Not conn Is Nothing Then
            conn.Close()
        End If
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try

End Function
```